# RethinkDB Python Driver Windows

Tags: windows, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I would need the import function of the rethinkDB. To use this function, the python driver has to be used. There is a tutorial in the documentation, which explains how to install the python driver for Linux, but there is no explanation for windows.

Is it possible to get the python driver for windows? If yes, how?
Or is there another option how to import a (geo)json file, e.g. with Java?

Comment: If you install Python, you can use `pip install rethinkdb` to install the RethinkDB Python driver on Windows.